# Can params keyword be expressed via WSDL definition

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, parameters

The application I am developing is exposing service metadata for a WCF service implementing following service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    object Execute( string action, params object[] args );
}
```

After adding service reference I noticed that there is no `params` keyword in the service contract and its implementation in the generated `Reference.cs` file.

Is there `params` counterpart in WSDL definition?

Or is `params` something that is specific to C# and cannot be expressed via WSDL definition so service client generator does not know that `params` should be added during generation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` is just syntactic sugar which allows you calling the method expecting array of objects without passing the prepared array. WCF doesn't know anything about this - it should just expect array of objects. Btw. passing array of `object` to service operation can leads to multiple problems because if you pass an custom object as parameter WCF may not know how to serialize the object.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed the confirmation. I am very aware of the problems. I do not know which types the service might expect. Therefore, the service is configured with a custom endpoint behavior that enables addition of service known types via configuration. Hm, I am not quite sure whether the problem will occur during serialization of passed object (it's client side, right?). I thought it would occur only during deserialization since the service has no knowledge on the type of part of received SOAP message (when using SOAP). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you use known types and types are described in WSDL you should be ok.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to include custom data in WSDL definition that could be used by a custom service reference generator tool to include `params` keyword. Do you happen to know whether WSDL has an element that could contain arbitrary XML?

Comment: Yes it has - WSDL offers extensibility points but it would require you to write custom svcutil like tool to be able to use such custom extensions when generating client code.